# How can I compile .C to .exe and edit the view?

Tags: c, exe

I wrote 2 programs in C (one encoder and one decoder with random encryption key every second) and I want to compile those 2 programs to .exe to publish it.

Can you please help me how to compile it?

I tried with Visual Studio and Pycharm with tkinter. But it's like a totally new language for me. In Linux I compiled it via terminal to .exe.

Comment: Which *view* do you want to edit? Where does graphic come into the game? In how far are Python related tools as Pycharm and tkinter related to compiling a C program?

Comment: You have listed Visual studio. What's wrong with that? It should compile and link .C to .EXE nicely in most cases.

Comment: _At linux i compiled it via terminal to .exe._ Same works on Windows or mac or which operating system you are using. Neverthless your question is imho of topic.

Comment: I tryed to rewrite the code to python i mean. At visual studio i could not find C programm. only C# and CPP and i saw many differences at the code. I use windows 10

Comment: @δημητρηςτιτος In Visual Studio, start new project Visual C++, Win32, Console app. Try also `cl` (CL) from command line - it will start the command line compiler.

Comment: I have Visual studio 2017 express and it does not have  win32. Only window console application visual c++ :(

Comment: Again: What **view** are you talking about?

Comment: **Clarify** your question otherwise it will be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile to `.exe` open the `command prompt` and type this:

`gcc fileName.c` - compiling and linking, produces `a.exe`

or

`gcc -c fileName.c` - only compiling, produces `fileName.o` object file

`gcc -o test filename.o` - linking and produces `test.exe`

If there are more than 1 source file you can do the just compiling part for all files and generate object files.Then do the linking by adding their names in the command.Of curse  this is applicable if there are less files but for a bigger project you have to write a makefile.

Comment: I have to download something and follow some moves to use gcc right? Cause i tryed it and told me "'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: you have to download a compiler first.These things are compiler commands

Comment: can you please guidance me how to do it?

Comment: what OS are you using?For windows i recomend getting minGW

Comment: I have windows 10. So i have only to download the minGW or it needs any installation?

Comment: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Installing_MinGW_under_Windows

Comment: I installed the minGW and whe i try : gcc encoder.c encoder.exe . It writes 'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: add C:\MinGW\bin in PATH

Comment: I just did it and it writes : c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file encoder.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I wrote : gcc encoder.c -o encoder.exe

Comment: encoder.exe is open and that's why you get this error.Open task manager -> Processes and kil the process for that exe

Comment: There is no open task encoder :( Sorry about your time, but i did not understand what i did wrong and did not compile :/ Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: maybe your antivirus software is locking it somehow

Answer (score 2):

You are searching for a **compiler**, like [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) or [Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/cxx_status.html). If you are developing on Windows, I recommend [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/) (GCC for Windows). Then you can compile and link your source code to an .exe file using the commandline, just like you did on linux.

Your IDE (like Visual Studio) is basically doing the same, you just don't see it. If your IDE is configured properly, it should work just fine.

Comment: I have to download something and follow some moves to use gcc right? Cause i tryed it and told me "'gcc' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: He added a link to MinGW, which is basically a gcc version (along with other things) for windows. Just follow the link, install MinGW and you would be able to use gcc.